# AngularJS accessing an attribute in a directive from a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I need to pass an Id defined in the directive to the associated controller such that it can be used in a HTTP Get to retrieve some data.

The code works correctly in its current state however when trying to bind the Id dynamically, as shown in other questions, the 'undefined' error occurs.

The Id needs to be defined with the directive in HTML to meet a requirement. Code follows;

Container.html

```
<div ng-controller="IntroSlideController as intro">
   <div intro-slide slide-id="{54BCE6D9-8710-45DD-A6E4-620563364C17}"></div>
</div>
```

eLearning.js

```
var app = angular.module('eLearning', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('IntroSlideController', ['$http', function ($http, $scope, $attrs) {
    var eLearning = this;
    this.Slide = [];
    var introSlideId = '{54BCE6D9-8710-45DD-A6E4-620563364C17}'; //Id to replace

    $http.get('/api/IntroSlide/getslide/', { params: { id: introSlideId } }).success(function (data) {
        eLearning.Slide = data;
    });
}])
    .directive('introSlide', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: '/Modules/IntroSlide.html',
            controller: 'IntroSlideController',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
                 console.log(attrs.slideId); //Id from html present here
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Are the id's hard coded? The Controller should always be the source of truth, so it should already know the id's. If it doesn't something might not be right.

Comment: The id will be hardcoded into the HTML but not the controller - this will allow the Html to define which IntroSlide will presented on it.

Comment: hmmm.... So the view becomes the source of truth? I think that breaks the point of MVC. Would it be possible to move that information to somewhere else such as a query string? Alternatively, could you hard code that value into the controller and just have it set on the view using Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining a controller `div` that wraps around a directive, a more appropriate approach is to define a controller *within* the directive itself. Also, by defining an isolated scope for your directive, that `slide-id` will be available for use automatically within directive's controller (since Angular will inject `$scope` values for you):

```
.directive('introSlide', function () {
    // here we define directive as 'A' (attribute only)
    // and 'slideId' in a scope which links to 'slide-id' in HTML
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            slideId: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: '/Modules/IntroSlide.html',
        controller: function ($http, $scope, $attrs) {
            var eLearning = this;
            this.Slide = [];

            // now $scope.slideId is available for use
            $http.get('/api/IntroSlide/getslide/', { params: { id: $scope.slideId } }).success(function (data) {
                eLearning.Slide = data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now your HTML is free from wrapping `div`:

```
<div intro-slide slide-id="{54BCE6D9-8710-45DD-A6E4-620563364C17}"></div>
```

In your `IntroSlide.html`, you probably have references that look like `intro.*` (since your original code use `intro` as a reference to controller's `$scope`). You will probably need to remove the `intro.` prefix to get this working.

Comment: This is correct solution as it keeps your presentation separated from your application.

Answer (score 0):

Require your controller inside your directive, like this:

```
app.directive( 'directiveOne', function () {
      return {
        controller: 'MyCtrl',
        link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl){
           ctrl.myMethodToUpdateSomething();//use this to send/get some msg from your controller
        }
      };
    });
```